# Xcode 5 Documentation Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, documentation, appledoc

I wanted to describe my code like this

```
/** Loads and parses the XML file*/
+(NSMutableArray *)loadXML:(NSString *)table;
```

But when I try to use the quick help for loadXML: Xcode crashes with this Error:

```
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEPlugins/IDEPlugins-5064/IDEQuickHelp/Models/IDEQuickHelpContentCreator.m:321
Details:  Error creating XML document from clang-parsed comment block: Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=73 "Line 1: invalid character in attribute value
Line 1: attributes construct error
Line 1: Couldn't find end of Start Tag Function
" UserInfo=0x7fc78fb98500 {NSLocalizedDescription=Line 1: invalid character in attribute value
Line 1: attributes construct error
Line 1: Couldn't find end of Start Tag Function
}
```

Could anyone help me please?

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

Delete the "LaunchScreen.xib" from your project and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's time to submit a bug report to Apple's bug reporter.

If you restart your computer and re-launch Xcode, does the crash occur again?

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer!
I tried to restart OSX and Xcode but the problem is still there

Comment: FYI, I added your definition to one of my projects, and quick help worked for me without crashing.

Comment: Ok...
That's strange o_O